# Excel 2016 for Mac, having issues using a Macro that normally works on 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos, runtime-error, excel-2016

I am attempting to run macros on my Mac Excel 2016 version. Unfortunately, I get a run-time error 1004. The code normally works on Mac Excel 2011. Please help, assistance is much appreciated; I am not a coder.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyallworksheets()
'
' copyallworksheets Macro
' copy all worksheets to new workbooks
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+b
'
    Sheets("Beverages").Select
    Sheets("Beverages").Copy
    Cells.Select
    Range("A13").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Select
    Range("A13").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "Macintosh HD:Users:Jay:Desktop:EOM Uploads:Beverage Purchases.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

The 1004 error occurs on the following line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "Macintosh HD:Users:Jay:Desktop:EOM Uploads:Beverage Purchases.csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: YowE3K,

Thank you for that advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a security issue, try these steps:

> Click the **Microsoft Office** Button, and then click **Excel Options**.
>
> Click **Trust Center**.
>
> Click **Trust Center Settings**.
>
> Click **Macro Settings**.
>
> Click to select the **Trust access to the VBA project object model** check box.
>
> Click **OK** to close the **Excel Options** dialog box.

Credit to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813969/you-may-receive-an-run-time-error-when-you-programmatically-allow-acce